# Nginx: cannot access server or very slow response time when active connections is more 100

Tags: mysql, nginx, hhvm

I have install ubuntu 14.04, nginx, mariadb and hhvm on my VPS in order to run a Laravel application. However, the user cannot access to our server (or they need to wait with very long time) all the times when the active connections is more than 100. May I know that what possible reason causing this isssue? Here is log and config of my VPS.

cpu infor:

```
  processor       : 0
  vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
  cpu family      : 6
  model           : 45
  model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz
  stepping        : 7
  cpu MHz         : 1500.138
  cache size      : 15360 KB
  physical id     : 0
  siblings        : 12
  core id         : 0
  cpu cores       : 6
  apicid          : 0
  initial apicid  : 0
  fpu             : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level     : 13
  wp              : yes
```

ram:

```
3GB
```

top:
[image: top]

iotop:
[image: iotop]

nginx status:

```
Active connections: 112
server accepts handled requests
269927 269927 368061
Reading: 0 Writing: 2 Waiting: 110
```

nginx config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 6;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 4096;
use epoll;
multi_accept on;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;

http {
##
# Basic Settings
##

client_max_body_size 110m;
client_body_buffer_size 10K;
client_header_timeout 12;
client_body_timeout 12;
send_timeout 12;
sendfile on;

proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;

keepalive_timeout 12;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;
reset_timedout_connection on;

limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:5m;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log off;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_min_length 10240;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Cache Configs
##

open_file_cache max=100000 inactive=20s;
open_file_cache_valid 30s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
open_file_cache_errors on;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

server config:

```
  server {
     server_name www.xxx.com;
     return 301 $scheme://xxx.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    ##
    # Static File Caching
    ##

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
            expires 365d;
    }

    root /xxx/xxx.com/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xxx.com;

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    include hhvm-with-fallback.conf;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location @fallback {     
        try_files $uri =404;     
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;     
        include fastcgi_params;     
        fastcgi_index index.php;     
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;     
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;     
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

  }
```

mysql config:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_connections     = 500
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 600
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover          = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 128M
#open-files-limit   = 2000
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 64M
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
#query_cache_type       = DEMAND

#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

log_warnings        = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={0|1}]
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index

#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

hhvm php.ini

```
  ; php options
  session.save_handler = files
  session.save_path = /var/lib/php5
  session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

  ; hhvm specific 
  hhvm.log.level = Warning
  hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
  hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
  hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false
```

hhvm server.ini

```
      ; php options

      pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

      ; hhvm specific 

      hhvm.server.port = 9000
      hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
      hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
      hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
      hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
      hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
```

"show full processlist;" result

```
  +--------+------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
  | Id     | User | Host      | db            | Command | Time | State | Info                  | Progress |
  +--------+------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
  | 126338 | root | localhost | NULL          | Query   |    0 | init  | show full processlist |    0.000 |
  | 127981 | root | localhost | pa_db | Sleep   |    5 |       | NULL                  |    0.000 |
  +--------+------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Show nginx's server config and php config

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thank you for your comment. I already show the php and nginx server config

Comment: You didn't show nginx's server config.

Comment: In addition to Nginx configuration, which you haven't provided in full yet, it would also be nice to see the result of the "show full processlist" query to MySql at the time when the problem occurs. I am particularly interested in if there are any "stuck" queries — ones that are executed for more than 5 seconds. The query execution time is usually displayed in the 6th column.

Comment: @IvanTsirulev Here is the "show full processlist" result